TV series similar to "From"?
Looking for a TV series I remember watching prior 2019. After watching From it reminded me of a TV series that ran for about 2 seasons before it was canceled. It had to have run between 2008-2020 in New Zealand due to my age (the TV series was rated M.) They had planned another season and it was canceled, so has to be new enough that it was canceled before From came out; otherwise people would have said something on Google about From and this series sharing similar plot lines. It's not Wayward pines, I just finished watching this few days ago and the plot lines didn't match.
Main character was a man mid 30s with brown hair.
Plot start of story: He got lost and drove past a road sign/town sign. Once he was in the town he couldn't leave. I can't recall if he had other people in the car, unfortunately. Reminds me of the Escape episode "Coffee Break", as the town sign had a population counter on it, but is not this either.
Plot further along in story: He and another character teamed up to try and leave as they couldn't leave, they had to find a way out. He of course discovered that someone else had managed to leave or something & found information about how they left. One of the last episodes is the only one I remember as they left it on a cliff hanger with him promising people if he made it out he would find away back to help them leave. He managed to leave via swimming down a stream/river. It was the only way out. I remember someone died that was traveling with him trying to also escape the township, maybe was shot by someone trying to stop them leaving.

If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. Incorrect answers are an excellent chance to [edit] new details into your question, e.g. "I know that it can't be Tourist Trapped because there was a recurring plot point that dodo birds were being used as pets, and everyone spoke with a strong Southern accent."

This sounds like it might be the Wayward Pines series, released in 2015.

In the first season, Ethan Burke is a U.S. Secret Service agent investigating the disappearance of two fellow agents in the mysterious small town of Wayward Pines, Idaho. Ethan awakens from a car accident unable to contact the outside world and unable to leave. He finds one of the agents dead and the other, his former lover Kate Hewson, settled down in the seemingly idyllic town. But the inhabitants of Wayward Pines are trapped there by an electrified fence and set of rules enforced by the strict Sheriff Arnold Pope. Any attempt to escape is punished by a public execution known as a "reckoning", when the Sheriff slits the condemned's throat. Ethan reconnects with his wife and son while working to discover the truth.


And if I remember, this ran for 2 seasons.

Indeed, with the second season following a different character for plot-related reasons. Apparently, it was only meant to run for a single season, but after the first season's success (and some lingering plot threads), they renewed it.

I have watched Wayward pines (a few days ago) as this was suggested on a Google search. It is not the same series unfortunately. The plot doesn't match up as the person drove into the town (no accident like Wayward pines). Plus the main character escapes the township in one of the last episodes before they canceled the show via a river/stream.
